# How to update my member count through a specific channel name (NOT ID) python

Tags: python, rename, member, nextcord

I have tried looping in my bot. The loop is suppose to update the member counter. I wanted double check to see if this is correct as it doesn't update the stats. The channel itself can be made trough the command its the part of updating that I am having trouble with
any help is greatly appreciated. There is no error showing and I am really confused. Thank you in advance!

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands, tasks
from nextcord.webhook import async_

class stats(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
    


    @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def looped_task(self,):
        text_channel_list = []
        stats = len(self.guild.members)
        channel = self.client.get_channel.startswith('Members: ')
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                text_channel_list.append(channel)
                if channel == True:
                    await channel.edit(channel, name = f"Members: {stats}")
    
    
    @commands.command()
    async def stat(self, ctx):
        channel = self.client.get_channel.startswith('Members')
        stats = len(ctx.guild.members)
        await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"Members:{stats}", category=None)
        await ctx.send(f"Your Server has {stats} members")
                
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(stats(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your task? If not, it won't update it of course. When using tasks that loop, they need to be started as described in the [documentation](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html). Specifically the [task.start()](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#nextcord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)

You could add in this piece of code in your Cog to start it when the Cog itself is ready.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    self.looped_task.start()
```